# What's the deal with |Pipe-delimited| variables in connection strings?

Tags: .net, ado.net, syntax, macros, connection-string

I know that **|DataDirectory|** will resolve to `App_Data` in an ASP.NET application but is that hard-coded or is there a generalized mechanism at work along the lines of *%environment variables%*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the MSDN [Smart Client Data Blog](https://blogs.msdn.com/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx):

> In this version, the .NET runtime
>   added support for what we call the
>   DataDirectory macro. This allows
>   Visual Studio to put a special
>   variable in the connection string that
>   will be expanded at run-time...
>
> By default, the |DataDirectory|
>   variable will be expanded as follow:
>
> - For applications placed in a
>     directory on the user machine, this
>     will be the app's (.exe) folder.
> - For apps running under ClickOnce, this will be a special data folder
>     created by ClickOnce
> - For Web apps, this will be the App_Data folder
>
> Under the hood, the value for
>   |DataDirectory| simply comes from a
>   property on the app domain. It is
>   possible to change that value and
>   override the default behavior by doing
>   this:
>
> ```
> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", newpath)
> ```